# expected a identifier instead saw '('. expected a identifier instead saw ')'

Tags: javascript, bubble-sort, identifier

I am using bubble sort to sort a array but when I write swap function , I'm getting error when writing the line function swap(arr,j,j+1) I am getting the err" expected ')' to match from '('

```
function solve(N, arr){
 for (var i = 0; i < N; i++){
   for(var j = 0; j < (N - i - 1); j++){
     if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
      swap(arr, j, j + 1)
     }
   }
 }
 

function swap(arr,j,j+1) //getting error here "expected a identifier instead saw '('.  expected a identifier instead saw ')'. "[look at the screenshot ][1]
{
     var temp = arr[j];
       arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
       arr[j + 1] = temp;
}
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have an expression `j+1` as a parameter in your function.

```
function swap(arr, j, j + 1)
```

You cannot do that, you either rename `j + 1` to `k` for example. But why even send them both in the first place if `k = j + 1`? You could accomplish this by only using

```
function swap(arr,j)
{
     var temp = arr[j];
       arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
       arr[j + 1] = temp;
}
```

and calling the function just as

```
swap(arr,j);
```